# Cross-platform compatible sed command?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use `sed`, but I want to run properly both under Linux and Mac. Currently, I have something like this:

```
if test -f ${GENESISFILE};
then
    echo "Replacing ..."
    sed -i '' "s/ADDRESS/${ADDRESS}/g" ${GENESISFILE}
else
    echo "No such file"
fi
```

Now, the point is that using `-i ''` part it runs properly under Mac, but doesn't under Linux, and if I remove it then it doesn't work under Mac. What's proper way to make it cross-platform compatible?

Comment: Check if the script is running on Mac or Linux.

Comment: This is part of the script, it runs on Mac just fine with -i '' part, the problem is it doesn't under Linux, and if remove -i '' part then it doesn't run properly on Mac.

Comment: ... and if running on Mac use BSD `sed` syntax and if running on Linux use GNU `sed` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -i '' "s/ADDRESS/${ADDRESS}/g" ${GENESISFILE}
```

use this cross-platform Perl one-liner, which runs OK on both Linux and macOS:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/ADDRESS/$ENV{ADDRESS}/g' ${GENESISFILE}
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. Use `-i` alone, without `.bak`, to skip making the backup.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)